Why are Bitcoin signet test coins so difficult to obtain?
Recently there have been a number of tests for the potential staking of Bitcoin.  The test require participants to stake Signet coins which are test coins delivered from faucets.  These faucets never seem to work but in reviewing the mempool.space it is evident someone’s receiving these coins.  Does anyone know why in a very slow demand season or period like now, signet coins remain difficult to acquire? I am not asking how to obtain signet coins! The root of my question is why are those faucets not working for requestors even when the excitement for them is very low. Look at mempool and you’ll see how slow requests are currently. Now try and obtain Signet coins. Share your findings.

This question is similar to: How can I get signet coins?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Faucets not working… why?  See changes to question. Thanks for taking the time to review.
